# Divisible by a and b, but not a*b

Tags: least-common-multiple

Is it possible to have a scenario where any number *n* is divisible by and number *a* and is also divisible by a number *b*, but is not divisible by *a*b*

The origin of this question was my way of thinking about the classical FizzBuzz coding problem.

Comment: $12$ is divisible by $4$ and $6$..

Comment: Yes, as long as they are not primes.

Comment: Every non-prime fails this test. Let $n$ be a composite number. Then there exists some positive integer $1<a<n$ such that $a \vert n$ and yet $a\cdot n$ cannot divide $n$.

Comment: Also, $\color{Red}{n}\mid n$ and $\color{Blue}{n}\mid n$ but $\color{Red}{n}\color{Blue}{n}\nmid n$ for all $n>1$.

Comment: Okay. That is the obvious answer. I get it now. I think that I was thinking a and b were prime, but didn't realize that's what I was thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $n=18$, $a=9$, $b=6$ then 
$ab = 54$

$54$ does not divide $18$.

For it to be true $a$ and $b$ should be coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. For example $4$ is divisible by $2$ and $4$ but not $8$. However if $a$ and $b$ are coprime the result is true.